# js положение scroll не запоминает

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему скролл не запоминает своё положение.

На странице /ajax/select/dialog.php работает запоминание

```
  <script>
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var div = document.querySelector('#slider');
   var scroll = localStorage.getItem('scroll')||0;
   div.scrollTop = scroll;
   div.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   localStorage.setItem('scroll', div.scrollTop);
   })
   });

    </script>
```

Далее с другой странице я вывожу скриптом /ajax/select/dialog.php :

```
<script>

        function show()  
        {  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "../../ajax/select/dialog.php",  
                cache: true,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#dtr").html(html);   
                }  
            });  
        }  
          $(document).ready(function(){  
            show();  
            setInterval('show()',3000);  
        });  
</script>
```

И запоминание не работает, каждые 3 заданные секунды страница дергается вверх.

Подскажите как быть в данной ситуации.

Comment: Похоже что обрабатывать скролл нужно не в подгружаемой странице, а на странице с аяксом.

Comment: Если #dtr сам имеет полосы прокрутки то скролить нужно его, иначе страницу на которую загружается контент.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Получилось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если страница загружается аяксом, то что бы восстановить позицию скрола нужно запоминать/востанавливать позицию основной страницы.
Если аякс загружается в div с overflow, т.е. скролируемый, то вероятно нужно запоминать/востанавливать позицию div.